# img src tag not displaying image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to display social media icons at the footer of a webpage using the img src tag (should be simple). The image isn't showing up and I can't find the problem.

html

```
<div class="mastfoot">
    <div class="inner">
        <p><a href="#"><img src="/images/twitter.png"></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm probably overlooking something simple but thanks in advance!

Here's what I'm getting when I inspect image file in browser.

[image]

Here's code for CSS inner class

```
.site-wrapper-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.inner {
    padding: 30px;
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/opsh1os8/

Comment: Make sure that the path is correct. Try images/twitter.png instead of /images/twitter.png. Can you add css source code for inner class?

Comment: make sure your image name is correct.. and does not have some special characters like "#"

Comment: i noticed you did not close you IMG tag...

Comment: and the compiler is detecting it as Text/HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed problem, I redirected the path to my assets folder which is where the images folder is,

```
<img src="assets/twitter.png">
```

And it worked. Don't really know why though!

Comment: Be careful, you are probably pointing to the wrong folder, or the wrong image. You may have 2 twitter images that are the same. If this is a project that will go live, it may break when you put in on your host.

Comment: @nextstep I'm having the exact same issue with a transparent twitter logo in Chrome Canary 64. You're not crazy... there is an issue of sorts. The image does come in as 33kb 200 code but is 0x0px. color versions load just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Open up your Console (Right Click + Inspect Element in most browsers) to see if your URL for the image is broken.

You can also click on the URL that it's generating. Chances are the `/` at the start of the path is not what you want. That goes to your root path, not the current directory. Try using `images/twitter.png` instead.

The path you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
http://localhost/myproject/images/twitter.png
```

But because of the initial `/`, this is the URL that your browser would look for:

```
http://localhost/images/twitter.png
```

Comment: The url is correct and the image is not displaying for some reason

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to check what URL the browser is seeing, by looking at the source code of the page having the broken image link. For example, in Firefox via Tools-->Web Developer-->Page Source, in Google Chrome via -->More tools --> Developer Tools --> Elements. That helped me see what URL the browser was seeing for the image, then I moved the image and changed the URL to make it work.